# Await message from user in Direct Message Discord js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot to wait for a  direct message in this case some name and write it back to same user in direct message in this case me.

I try to use `message.author.awaitMessages` but console return:

> TypeError: message.author.awaitResponse is not a function

```
message.author.send('Write your Name')
      .then(function(){
        message.channel.awaitMessages(response => message.content, {
          max: 1,
          time: 300000000,
          errors: ['time'],
        })
        .then((collected) => {
            message.author.send(`Your Name is: ${collected.first().content}`);
          })
          .catch(function(){
            message.channel.send('You didnt write your name');
          });
      });
  }
```

Comment: While calling the message.author.send can you confirm that `message` is definately the variable and it's not `msg`? Discord.js hello world uses `client.on('message', msg) => {` .     In your case i think you need to change the `msg` here to `message`

Answer (score 1):

Try `message.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages`

Check more info in the documentation
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=dmChannel

Answer (score 0):

The `Message` class has the property `author`, which is of the type `User` class (as seen in the docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author)), and the `User` class does not have the function `awaitResponse(...)`, which is why you are seeing that error. See documentation of the User class [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User).

I would recommend using `message.channel.awaitMessages` and checking the messages' `.author` property if you are checking for responses from a specific person.

Answer (score 0):

`message.author` is from the `User` class which does not contain the `awaitResponse()` function. Use `message.member` (returns a `GuildMember`) instead of `message.author`